# Any way to retrieve build info for apt/dpkg installed packages?

Tags: apt, dpkg, deb

I've had this .deb package that I built with, I think, `checkinstall`, directly from its git source; and it got a version like `libmypackage1_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb`. Then after a some months, I did a `git pull` in the same source, and built new version of the .deb, but it again got the `libmypackage1_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb` name.

Now, after some months, I am not sure anymore, which of the debs is installed - the first, or the second build - because the git hash of the commit I've built does not get included in the file name or version.

However, I've kept the build outputs from both runs, and I can see a `libmypackage1_0.10.7-1_armhf.buildinfo`. So, my question is - when I install such a "built" package via `dpkg -i ...`, does any information from the .buildinfo end up somewhere, so that I can query it with `apt`, `dpkg`, or another tool? Basically I want to query, for instance, "what is the build date of the currently installed `libmypackage1_0.10.7-1`?" - or any other piece of info that would help me discriminate the two builds.

If we need to navigate a bit away from the `libmypackage` example - let's say I want to retrieve the same info about the `bash` package; I know I can do this, for instance:

```
$ apt-show-versions bash
bash:armhf/stretch 4.4-5 uptodate
```

Could I issue some command, which would tell me, for instance, the build date for this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buildinfo` information isn’t currently kept with `deb` packages.

There are a number of other ways to determine the information you need. `deb` packages preserve timestamps, so assuming you can trust them (which seems to be the case here), looking at the timestamps of the files installed by the packages will give you a good approximation of their build timestamp:

```
ls -ldtR $(dpkg -L libmypackage) | grep -v ^d | head
```

If you still have the `deb`s, you can check the installed files against their checksums to determine which one is installed:

```
debsums libmypackage1_0.10.7-1_armhf.deb
```

To link a `deb` file to its build information, you can use the checksums in the corresponding `changes` file.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for that @StephenKitt - great info!

Comment: There's https://buildinfos.debian.net/ f.ex.